# what is sqlalchemy query() function doing actually?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am reading SQLAlchemy [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#adding-new-objects) and I am a bit confused about the query() function.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.db', echo=True)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import Sequence
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(12))
    def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()enter code here
ed_user = User('ed', 'Ed Jones', 'edspassword')
session.add(ed_user)
our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
session.add_all([User('wendy', 'Wendy Williams', 'foobar'),User('mary', 'Mary Contrary', 'xxg527'),User('fred', 'Fred Flinstone', 'blah')])
session.commit()
```

the doc said

> **The Session will issue the SQL to persist Ed Jones as soon as is needed, using a process known as a flush. If we query the database for
>   Ed Jones, all pending information will first be flushed, and the query
>   is issued immediately thereafter.**

And if I run

```
our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
```

it actually issued

```
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO users (name, fullname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
('ed', 'Ed Jones', 'edspassword')
SELECT users.id AS users_id,
        users.name AS users_name,
        users.fullname AS users_fullname,
        users.password AS users_password
FROM users
WHERE users.name = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
('ed', 1, 0)
```

however, the database didn't get updated(it was empty) until session.commit() executed.

My questions are:
1. why the pending data got flushed and even it showed INSERT INTO users, the database was still empty?
2. the database didn't contain the flushed data, but if by running **ed_user.id** it returned me the the correct primary key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using transactions. Database transactions isolate different connections and ensure that you keep the database in a consistent state. Not until you commit the transaction can other connections see your changes.

Your SQLAlchemy connection can see all changes it made because it is party to its own transaction.

Note that the other option is to abort the transaction, and roll back all changes, and your new object will no longer exist in the database, in this connection or any other.

[Database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) are a general concept and not specific to SQLAlchemy.